# Formatting date using jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologise if this is a really basic question but I am using the following jquery plugin:
http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input

I want to change the date from YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YYYY using his suggestion under customisations. I tried to do the following which I thought would work but it completely breaks it:

```
$.extend(DateInput.DEFAULT_OPTS, {
  stringToDate: function(string) {
    var matches;
    if (matches = string.match(/^(\d{4,4})-(\d{2,2})-(\d{2,2})$/)) {
      return new Date(matches[1], matches[2] - 1, matches[3]);
    } else {
      return null;
    };
  },

dateToString: function(date) {
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    var dom = date.getDate().toString();
    if (month.length == 1) month = "0" + month;
    if (dom.length == 1) dom = "0" + dom;
    return date.dom + "/" + month + "/" + getFullYear();
  }
});
```

It's the following line where it all goes wrong:

```
return date.dom + "/" + month + "/" + getFullYear();
```

Could anyone offer a suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try putting the return value into a variable and then return it

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What is it doing? What's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the jQuery UI datepicker. Very easy to format the date

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks I think I'll just use that as it will be much easier than trying to debug this code.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need the "date" in date.dom:

try replacing this:

```
return date.dom + "/" + month + "/" + getFullYear();
```

with this:

```
return dom + "/" + month + "/" + getFullYear();
```